# Are wildcards available in setting up MiXplorer AutoTasks?

Tags: file-management, automation, 8.0-oreo

I want to set up an auto-task in MiXplorer to delete two types of files that another application creates – one appears in two different folders, and another is in one folder but has different numeric strings appended to it each time it's created. Is it possible to set a task for each with a wildcard that will work on either, like `/internalstorage/$/.crap.tmp` and/or `internalstorage/backups/system/crap_$` (where `$` is some wildcard character or string).

I tried asterisks but that didn't work, and tried figuring out if there was something to the regex renaming format that I could understand and use, but couldn't.

I'm using Android 8.0.0, MiXplorer 6.46.1.

Thanks much.

Comment: An automation app is a much better choice for the task at hand. Any particular reason for avoiding that?

Answer (score 1):

I am using version 6.54.0 of MIXplorer. Autotask does not have regex (widcards) options when deleting files. They are available for copying, moving and archiving files.

What you can do is:

- Create a `.sh` file with for example the following command to remove files:

```
#!/bin/sh
rm -f internalstorage/backups/system/crap_*
```

- Create a autotask, select Execute. Then on the File option, select the file created earlier.

The command above assumed that you know the path and part of filenames. Notice that I did not use the directory  `/internalstorage/$/.crap.tmp` as using `*` will lead to check all directories for `.crap.tmp` file.